# If an Exception is thrown up the calling chain are all its subclasses thrown as well?

Tags: java, exception

A java book used by one of the students that I tutor contains the following (Blue Pelican Java version 3.0.5b Charles Cook):

> If you have a method that throws an IOException up to the next level in the calling chain, we should be aware that in addition to IOException being thrown to the next level, all its subclasses are also thrown to the next level in the chain.

This seems obviously false, but is it correct? A version of this statement was posed on the student's exam, and was supposed to be true.

Also, the following code seems to be a counterexample to the claim:

```
public class ExceptionsTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Subclasses thrown");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Subclasses not thrown");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw that book in the garbage bin right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense on multiple levels and as worded is completely false.

Throwing an `IOException` does precisely that, throws an `IOException`.

Subclasses of `IOException` won't be caught, because they're not thrown.

Catching a *superclass* of an exception *will* catch the exception (although in this case it's `java.lang.Exception`, of course).

I'm not convinced the author is stating that if (say) an IOException is thrown then all IOException subclasses are also thrown. Based on reading the previous sections I *think* he's trying to make the point that if something declares it can throw an IOException it *also* means that IOException subclasses can be thrown.

It's worded horribly, but I have a difficult time believing the author thinks IOException subclasses are thrown when an IOException is thrown–he correctly points out that subclasses must be caught before their less-specific superclasses immediately prior. I find it more likely there was either an editing issue or it was just poorly stated.

Comment: I think Patashu has the right idea: the confusion is between a method that will when executed cause a particular exception to be thrown (and bubble up), and one which, according to its declaration, `throws` an exception.  Saying `throws SomeExceptionType` also implicitly says `throws ExceptionDerivedFromSomeExceptionType`.

Answer (score 4):

Did the book mean: 'If a method declares it throws Exception, then all subclasses of Exception can be thrown by it'? Because that's true in Java, but it doesn't tell you anything about the behaviour of catching exceptions and their subclasses (as the other answer suggests)

Comment: I think this is in the near neighborhood of what was meant by the author. In the text, the author could have correctly meant that if a method throws IOException that method can also throw subclasses of IOException without adding anything to the throws clause or handling the Exception. More generally, this should be true of any Exception class and its subclasses. 

I think its worth noting that even if this type of situation were to happen, e.g. the method were to throw a FileNotFoundException, the exception would be typecast to IOException and couldn't be caught by an IOException catch clause.

Comment: Example what I'm talking about: this is valid code because FileNotFoundException is a subclass of IOException: public void method() throws IOException { throw new FileNotFoundException(""); }

Comment: I think he means this part: 'the exception would be typecast to IOException and couldn't be caught by an IOException catch clause.' Doesn't catch (IOException e) {} catch all subclasses of IOException?

Comment: The other part of what I was saying is that if someone were to use method() from the example in my above code, and put it in a try catch block, the exception would be of type IOException, and not of type FileNotFoundException.

Comment: oops. typo.. haha. IOException should be FileNotFoundException at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not correct. First of all this is a static method and static methods dont get passed to the sub classed. Second this one does not throw an exception. It only handles it. By throwing an exeption I think the book author meant was declaring the method with a `throws` keyword.

for example

```
class A {
 void x() throws IOException {}
}
```

if :

```
class B extends A {
@overries
void x() {}
}
```

Even though the overriden method in B does not explicity throw it, anyone who uses the method in B must handle the IOException.

```
A a = new B();
a.x();
```

Compiler will complain. You must use

```
A a = new B();
try {
a.x();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

So the bottomline is the author is correct in a way.

Comment: Rereading the question, I don't think this is what the Author meant. He says that subclasses specifically of IOException are thrown if a method throws IOException. What he doesn't say is that classes that have methods that throw IOException will have subclasses that have methods that throw IOException.